# Java jna EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION after invoking C# dll

Tags: c#, database-connection, user-defined-functions, access-violation, jna

I use JNA to call a 3. party provided .dll written in C#. This is my code using the dll:

```
public class Main{
public interface AirtrackDLL extends Library{
    AirtrackDLL INSTANCE = 
    (AirtrackDLL)Native.loadLibrary("atproc32.dll",AirtrackDLL.class);  
    static interface TestPing extends Callback{
        short invoke(short param);
    }   
    static interface TestDBConnection extends Callback{
        short invoke();
    }
    public short TestPing(TestPing callbackparam);
    public short TestPing(short param);
    public short TestDBConnection(TestDBConnection callbackparam);  
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AirtrackDLL dll = AirtrackDLL.INSTANCE;
System.out.println("Result ohne callback : " + dll.TestPing((short)3));
short res = dll.TestPing(new AirtrackDLL.TestPing() {
    @Override
    public short invoke(short param) {
        System.out.println(param);
        return (short)0;
    }
});
System.out.println("Result mit callback : " + res);
short res1 = dll.TestDBConnection(new AirtrackDLL.TestDBConnection() {      
@Override
        public short invoke() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
    }
});
System.out.println(res1);
}
}
```

When I run the code the TestPing(short param)- Function will be executed correctly. The TestDBConnection()-Function gives the following Exception:

---

Result without callback : 30
Result with callback : 80

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x05cae065, pid=4940, tid=1464

JRE version: 7.0_25-b17
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
Problematic frame:
C  [atproc32.dll+0x27e065]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
D:\Entwicklungstools\Java\workspace\AFPS_Airport_Service\hs_err_pid4940.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.

### See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please show the native declarations.

Comment: thanks 4 your reply @technomage. I don't have the dll-Code. I just have the Methods and Params the dll needs and gives. In this case it is the functions (TestPing(short param) and TestDBConnection())deklared in the interfaces. The function TestPing(short param) runs without a problem....

Comment: @technomage try and get it 4 you. not shore if I can....let's give it a try.

Comment: If you have a header file, it will include the declarations of your native functions, which represent the basic information the compiler (and thus JNA) requires in order to properly map calls into the binary DLL.

Comment: Hey @technomage thanks for your help. we solved the problem. The dll I'm calling is C#. The C# calls a C++ and returns values. No wonder the  Pointers are not working after getting back into the java world. How can this Questions be set to solved?